# How to run a class in the test package that is not junit or testNG with gradle

Tags: java, junit, gradle

Our build setup is such that we have runnable classes that are executed during our development and not during live production code. These runnable classes are housed in the test directory with our jUnit tests and property files.

```
sourceSets {
...
test {
    java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
}
...
}
```

One such file is an embedded jetty web server, which is run from command line. We run the file in debug mode to boot a local runnable copy of the project. Is it possible to run the file, in debug mode- with gradle, without having to include it in main source sets?

We would prefer not to use the Jetty plugin for gradle.

Comment: Take a look at this example (but depend on 'testClasses' rather than 'classes') http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/gradle-goodness-run-java-application.html

Comment: Is it your suggestion to create another task to handle this specific case? Is this not handled by default with Gradle?